# npm start not opening localhost3000 in react app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, localhost

It's my first time using react. Whenever I type `npm start`[image: npm start image], this pop up appear,[image: pop up image].

I select google and it's open up this page[image: npm] not the localhost.

There's no problem in installing react though.

**My Package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Tried** I tried to ask a problem related to not opening of local host in react.
**Expect** I'm expecting a solution to it.

Comment: add `scripts` in `package.json` to your question

Comment: try setting a default browser on your PC. To do this you can follow *Select Start > Settings > Apps > Default apps*

Comment: @Salman Malik, it's my default browser.

Comment: @Salman Malik, shared it you can see.

Comment: Can you remove that ```"development":[/...]``` instance from ```package.json``` and try again.?

Comment: @SalmanMalik, still not working

Comment: Try cleaning npm cache :   npm cache clean --force

Comment: @SalmanMalik ,  thanks a lot for the help. I was first running it on VS Code PowerShell, but when I run it on Command prompt, it works out. Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 0):

I was first running it on vs code PowerShell terminal[image: terminal with powershall]. But when I run it on command prompt, it work out[image: terminal with command prompt].